# How to get only the last name when using \citeauthor{}, even though different authors in my bibliography have this last name?

Tags: biblatex, authoryear-comp

There are two authors in my PhD thesis's bibliography, say A. B. Smith and C. D. Smith.

The works by A. B. Smith are from the 1920s and 1930s and I cite him many times. The work of C. D. Smith is from 2002 and I cite him only once. But because of this work by C. D. Smith, whenever I write, e.g. `\citeauthor{Smith1928}`, \parencite{Smith1928}, and `\textcite{Smith1928}`, I get "`A. B. Smith`", "`(A. B. Smith, 1928)`, and "`A. B. Smith (1928)`". I would like to get, instead, "`Smith`", "`(Smith, 1928)`", and "`Smith (1928)`". There is no ambiguity with C. D. Smith. On the occasion I cite C. D. Smith, however, I would like to get "`C. D. Smith (2002)`", not "`Smith (2002)`".

Ideally, I would like not to change my global settings for this. I  would prefer to use new commands, such as `\citeauthornoinitials{...}`, `\parencitenoinitials{...}`, and `\textcitesnoinitials{...}`.

How could I do this? My biblatex settings are as follows:

```
\usepackage[sorting=nyt, style=authoryear-comp, backend=biber, uniquelist=false, maxbibnames=10, maxcitenames=2, doi=false, autolang=other, useprefix=true, datecirca=true]{biblatex}
```